# SQL Server error - Incorrect syntax for definition of the 'TABLE' constraint

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

T-SQL error on SQL 2008 when I run this code.

This type of question has been asked a few times in the past on Stack Overflow, and is normally to do with a comma being in the wrong place, but for the life of me I can't see what is wrong with the following SQL

```
CREATE TABLE IntroducerSupportLink
( 
IntroducerSupportLinkId int identity, 
IntroducerId nvarchar(12) not null, 
SupportStaffId nvarchar(12) not null, 
Status numeric(5),
SupportStaffType numeric(5),
CreatedDateTime datetime not null,
CONSTRAINT PK_IntroducerSupportLink_IntroducerSupportLinkId Primary key(IntroducerSupportLinkId),
CONSTRAINT FK_IntroducerSupportLink_IntroducerId foreign key(IntroducerId)    REFERENCES Introducer(introducerId),
CONSTRAINT FK_IntroducerSupportLink_SupportStaffId foreign key(SupportStaffId) REFERENCES Introducer(introducerId),
CONSTRAINT DF_IntroducerSupportLink_CreatedDateTime DEFAULT (GETDATE())
)
```

It runs if the last (default) constraint is commented out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following,

```
CREATE TABLE IntroducerSupportLink
( 
    IntroducerSupportLinkId int identity, 
    IntroducerId nvarchar(12) not null, 
    SupportStaffId nvarchar(12) not null, 
    Status numeric(5),
    SupportStaffType numeric(5),
    CreatedDateTime datetime not null DEFAULT GETDATE(),

    CONSTRAINT PK_IntroducerSupportLink_IntroducerSupportLinkId Primary key(IntroducerSupportLinkId),
    CONSTRAINT FK_IntroducerSupportLink_IntroducerId foreign key(IntroducerId)    REFERENCES Introducer(introducerId),
    CONSTRAINT FK_IntroducerSupportLink_SupportStaffId foreign key(SupportStaffId) REFERENCES Introducer(introducerId)
)
```

You can also do this thing inline

```
CreatedDateTime datetime not null CONSTRAINT "constraints_CreatedDateTime" DEFAULT GETDATE(),
```

You can not define DEFAULT constraints at table level by design, see [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx)

Comment: I wanted to name the default constraint, which this answer won't do

Answer (score 3):

You didn't "attach" the last constraint to any column.
To do that with a `DEFAULT` constraint, you must use it on the column definition itself (see full syntax [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx))

Comment: I think this is correct I need to have the CONSTRAINT definition with the column definition

Answer (score 0):

Try below code..

```
create TABLE IntroducerSupportLink5
( 
IntroducerSupportLinkId int identity, 
IntroducerId nvarchar(12) not null, 
SupportStaffId nvarchar(12) not null, 
Status numeric(5),
SupportStaffType numeric(5),
CreatedDateTime datetime not null constraint DF_IntroducerSupportLink_CreatedDateTime DEFAULT (GETDATE()),

CONSTRAINT PK_IntroducerSupportLink_IntroducerSupportLinkId Primary key(IntroducerSupportLinkId),
CONSTRAINT FK_IntroducerSupportLink_IntroducerId foreign key(IntroducerId)    REFERENCES Introducer(introducerId),
CONSTRAINT FK_IntroducerSupportLink_SupportStaffId foreign key(SupportStaffId) REFERENCES Introducer(introducerId)
)
```